# compare string with the retrieved value in grails controller

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I am trying to create a login action for login. I am getting the value from database. But the problem is that when I check the value with a string it's doesn't work properly and the else part executed and shows the message in the browser. I am using grails 2.1.0. I have no idea how to do it although I assume that this is a so normal problem. Can anyone please help me on this? Here is my code below :

```
def loginAction = {
    def username = params?.username
    def password = params?.password
    def user = Login.findAllByUsernameAndPassword(username, password)
    def status = user.status
    def role = user.role
    println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> "+role);

    if(role == 'admin'){
        render "Admin Login"
    }else if(role == "teacher"){
        render "Teacher's Login"
    }else if(role == "student"){
        render "student login"
    }else{
        flash.message = message(code: "Log-In failed, Please try again !!!")
        redirect(controller:"login",action:"login")
    }
}
```

Note that, the println works and give the output below :

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> [admin]
```

Comment: Hah! My proposition is: Don't create your own security, use known(spring security plugin, for example)

Comment: @Mr.Cat I have no idea how to do it. Can you please guide me for that ?!

Comment: http://blog.springsource.org/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `.findAllBy`, so you have a list of users, with one element in this list. As a result, role variable have `[admin]` value (see provided output), it's a list of roles. List of strings, not a string.

You're comparing this list with `admin` as a string value. So, that's right `["admin"] != "admin"`

Just use `findBy` instead, like:

```
def user = Login.findByUsernameAndPassword(username, password)
```

Comment: thanks a lot Igor. I am using it for now But I will have to use Mr. Cat's advice for security.

Comment: Yes, MrCat right, it's much better to use Spring Security instead of own implemetation